# How to add y value in piechart in highcharts as legend

Tags: highcharts

I have a Piechart made of highcharts plugin,Its working fine and my legend is also working fine.But here the value of 'y' that is 12,10,33 is not showing with my legend.I need to show this value with % for ex: yellow slice-12% ,Red Slice-10% etc.,Below is my code.Thanks in advance.

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500"></div>
```

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500"></div>
<script>
$(function () {
    new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'pie',
            height: 450,
            width: 450
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text : '',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                shadow: false,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
 legend: {
    align: 'right',
    layout: 'vertical',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: 0,
    y: 0
},
        series: [{
            innerSize: '60%',   
            outerSize: '40%',   
            showInLegend: true,
            data: [
                {name: 'Yellow Slice', y: 12, color: 'yellow'},
                {name: 'Red Slice', y: 10, color: 'red' },
                {name: 'Blue Slice', y: 33, color: 'blue'},
                {name: 'Green Slice', y: 20, color: 'green'}
            ],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,

            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: check this doc https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter

Answer (score 0):

You want the `dataLabels.formatter`. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels
There are also a bunch of settings you can change to adjust the placement and the connector.

https://jsfiddle.net/jsormpjj/

```
$(function() {
  new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'pie',
      height: 450,
      width: 450
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      text: '',
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        shadow: false,
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      align: 'right',
      layout: 'vertical',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    series: [{
      innerSize: '60%',
      outerSize: '40%',
      showInLegend: true,
      data: [{
          name: 'Yellow Slice',
          y: 12,
          color: 'yellow'
        },
        {
          name: 'Red Slice',
          y: 10,
          color: 'red'
        },
        {
          name: 'Blue Slice',
          y: 33,
          color: 'blue'
        },
        {
          name: 'Green Slice',
          y: 20,
          color: 'green'
        }
      ],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return this.point.name + ' - ' + this.point.y + '%';
        }

      }
    }]
  });
});
```